# How to ask permission or automatically set the phone's full screen on settings - android studio

Tags: android, permissions, fullscreen, android-permissions

I am trying to set my activity to full screen using this code below:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }
```

But I am getting a black color navigation bar on certain phones because of the condition on settings -> display where certain phones need to permit apps to use a fullscreen mode. To address this issue I decided that I need to implement a permission checker when the activity inflates. If there is another way please tell me and I will try to implement it.

Edit:
Here is the link of the conditions for phones that I am talking about:
https://www.gottabemobile.com/how-to-enable-full-screen-apps-on-galaxy-s10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file put

`android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"`
or

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and in your activity call `hideSystemUI()`; before setting the content view
like this :

```
final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 1):

this problem happen with me for 2 different devices and this because of the front camera notch or screen cutout.

I used this code in oncreate() :

```
hideSystemUI();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) { 
getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES; }
```

Or in the theme style xml file add this line :

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```